# Unity Shader: Overlapping two Layers with the same stencil value

Tags: user-interface, shader, unity-game-engine, shaderlab

I'm trying to write a shader for unity that will remove all overlapping fragments of the underlying objects. I found different solutions for this problem, which were really helpful.

For me this Link ([Unity shader highlighting overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574227/unity-shader-highlighting-overlaps)) was the most usefull one.

But now i have another problem. In the pictures you can see 6 buttons which normally have the same size and a transparent background. If one of these buttons gets selected, it overlaps its neighbours.

The following picture shows how it should look like with a custom shader. I have solved the problem by cutting a hole trough the background to show the image, but now i want to add a text to these buttons; if i would do the same thing again, the text would look scraggy.

[Menubutton correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57k5J.jpg)

The following code shows you how i solved my problem by cutting a hole into the transparent box:

```
    Shader "Custom/GUI/Mask" {
    Properties
    {
        _Color("Color (white = none)", COLOR) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _CutOff("Cut off", Range(-0.001,1)) = 0.1
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Geometry" }
        LOD 100

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ZWrite off

        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 0
                Comp Equal
                Pass IncrSat
                Fail IncrSat
            }

            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
                uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;
                float4 _Color;
                float _CutOff;

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    float4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                    color.rgb *= _Color.rgb;
                    color.a *= _Color.a;

                    if (color.a <= _CutOff)
                    {
                        discard;
                    }
                    return color;
                }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            ZWrite off

            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1
                Comp Less
            }

            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                float4 _Color;
                uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.uv;
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    fixed4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                    color.a = 0;
                    return color;
                }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            Stencil
            {
                Ref 2
                Comp Less
            }

            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _Color;

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.uv;
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    fixed4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                    color.a = 0;
                    return color;
                }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

This picture shows, how it would look like without a custom shader which removes the overlapping parts. In this picture you can also see, that the transparent background has normally a stencil value of 0 and when it overlaps, the value changes to 1. The problem is that the image on the background has also a stencil value of 1. So if i would remove all object with a stencil value of 1, i would remove all images on the transparent backgrounds. By the way the image and the background contain the same shader.

[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrggV.jpg)

Can you please help me to solve the problem without cutting a hole into the transparent box? The cutting through option has the problem, if i have round images, which have some transparent pixels, the background shines through very bright.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem myself. For those who have the same problem, here is the solution.
I created two different shaders. I created one for the background and one for the picture in front of the background.

The following code is for the background:

```
    Shader "Custom/GUI/Background" {
    Properties
    {
        _Color("Color (white = none)", COLOR) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _CutOff("Cut off", Range(-0.001,1)) = 0.1
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Geometry-100" "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }
        LOD 100

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ZWrite off

        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 0
                Comp Equal
                Pass IncrSat
                Fail IncrSat
            }

            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
                uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;
                float4 _Color;
                float _CutOff;

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    float4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                    color.rgb *= _Color.rgb;
                    color.a *= _Color.a;

                    return color;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

And this one for the image:

```
    Shader "Custom/GUI/ImageShader"
    {
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Color (white = none)", COLOR) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
        LOD 100

            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            ZWrite off

        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 0
                Comp Equal
                Pass IncrSat
                Fail IncrSat
            }

        }

        // picture layer
        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 2
                Comp Equal
            }

            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                // make fog work
                #pragma multi_compile_fog

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                float4 _Color;

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o, o.vertex);
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    // sample the texture
                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                    col.rgb *= _Color.rgb;
                    col.a *= _Color.a;
                    // apply fog
                    UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                    return col;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

The Hierarchy is now: the background is on the bottom, then text and above the image.

To be honest, I’m not sure why it is working and I know that this is not the best answer, but I hope I can help all the people, which are having the same or nearly the same problem.