# How to render only Inside a 3d cube with 3D plane which is bigger than the cube?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGIFZ.png)

Hi, I just want to render a plane inside a 3D cube.
The problem is that it has to render only inside a cube, not outside.
is there any way to solve this problem?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l60g-G5RqU
I did watch this tutorial for it, but cannot go further.

Comment: The proper way would be to render to a texture and use that texture as your cube's texture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Shader highlighting overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574227/unity-shader-highlighting-overlaps).
Basically you detect the overlapping and render your plane only where the cube wrote into the stencil buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I tried to do with the overlaps shader, but  it looks like you can see outside meshes with the 3d cube, just like a window.

Comment: Do you want to use a cube only or some arbitraty mesh?

Comment: Cube only. I found this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549754/rendering-only-point-cloud-data-inside-a-box                                                         but, I try to render point cloud not surface. So, I upload a question again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549754/rendering-only-point-cloud-data-inside-a-box